# Undefined procedure error in prolog

Tags: prolog, logic

I'm new in Prolog and i have unknown error !
this is the error:

```
 ERROR: sa/0: Undefined procedure: {}/1
 Exception: (7) {s=abeer-> (parent(ahmad, abeer)->write('The father is Ahmad \n');write('no father !'));write('Nothing \n')} ?
```

this is the code:

```
male(ahmad).
female(abeer).
parent(ahmad,abeer).

sa:-
    write('Enter your car: \n'),
    read(FE),
    {  FE = abeer
    -> (  parent(ahmad,abeer)
       -> write('The father is Ahmad \n')
       ;  write('no father !')
       )    
    ;  write('Nothing \n')
    }.
```

Comment: replace `{ ... }` by `( ... )`

Comment: Thaaaaaaanx :) , you have the name that you deserve ;)